# throwing 3 dice and obtaining "4" "2" "1"

Tags: probability

How are you ?
There is an exercise that I want to do (not a homework) and I need some help to understand my mistakes:

We play "$421$" by simultaneously throwing three dice until the moment we get the values $​​4,2$ and $1$. What is the probability that the goal is reached in less than $4$ throws?

Well,I tried this :

- E = "Having $4$ and $2$ and $1$"
- P(E) = $\frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{6} * 3$ (three possible way of having $421$) = $0.138$
- P(E*) = 0.9861
- List item

**Using geometric law:**

- $P(X=1) = 0.138 * 0.9861^0 = 0.138$
- $P(X=2) = 0.138 * 0.9861^1 = 0.01360956$
- $P(X=3) = 0.138 * 0.9861^2 = 0.01342174$
- $P(X<4) = 0.16503013$

I know that i'm wrong and the solutions manual says that the answer is $0.081$. I just want some help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: $3!=6$ ways to get there: 124 142 214 241 412 421

Comment: That's true ! My bad, thank you and have a nice day. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability to have the triplet $\{1,2,4\}$ where the order is not requested (you have 6 possibile ways, not 3) is $\frac{1}{36}$ thus using geometric CDF you have

$$P(X\le 3)=1-(35/36)^3\approx 0.081$$

Comment: You're right , Thanks and have a nice day :)